# How to typeset French quotation marks in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, french

How to typeset French quotation marks in plain TeX?

```
<<~This is the {\LaTeX} way.~>>
```

I might need to use European Computer Modern (or Latin Modern?) but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: If I try to use those LaTeX ligatures in a TeX file, I end up with inverted exclamation marks (which is the expected behaviour).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\font\rm=ecrm1000 \rm

<<~This is the {\TeX} way.~>>

\bye
```

Comment: That was easier than what I thought, thanks

Comment: On the other hand, something like `\'equipe` would no longer really work.

Comment: @egreg true but if someone chooses to use plain tex they presumably know how to set up document commands such as accents.  It's only possible to answer the questions as asked, not define an entire format suitable for document production in an answer here.

Comment: `équipe` would work just fine with a latin-1 file encoding

Answer (score 6):

You can use `opmac` (the documentation is quite scanty, though).

```
\input opmac
\input t1code
\csaccents

\fontfam[LM Fonts]

<<~\'equipe~>>

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like using L2FSS, you may try

```
\input plnfss
%\input t1lm.pfd % optional
\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}

<<~This is the plnfss way.~>>

\bye
```

If your document is Latin1 encoded, you may type accented letters directly; otherwise, for UTF8, add

```
\newcount\n
\catcode`\^^c3=\active
\def^^c3#1{\n=`#1\advance\n by 64 \char\n}
```

and you'll get the right glyph in your document.